# How to use C# package manager NuGet in ventuz

Tags: c#, nuget

I am using ventuz to do a presentation project that requires getting websocket data from the server. I follow the ventuz guide https://www.ventuz.com/support/help/latest/NodeLogicScript.html?itm=168
I wrote a C# .NET script, but I don't know how to use NuGet to get a dependency library in ventuz.

Comment: What NuGet package are you looking to use?

Comment: I know how to use DLL if you are still interested? So if you tell me what Nuget package you are using I might be able to find you a solution.